# Vertex Cover problem modification

Tags: graphs, np

Modification of vertex cover problem.
Given a graph G,does G have a vertex cover with 10 vertices? Is this problem still in NP?
Given a graph G and integer k, does G have a vertex cover with k vertices?
Is there any important difference between this two problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For fixed $c$ (i.e., we consider $c$ as a constant) this is trivially solvable in time $n^cm$ which is polynomial in $n$, however, if $k$ is part of the input, then $n^k$ would be considered exponential in $k$.

Vertex cover is solvable in $2^k \cdot n^{O(1)}$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But i still dont see the difference or i dont understand the idea.. Could you give me the idea of alg.?

Comment: Which of the algorithms?  If you are looking for a size 3 vertex cover, you simply try all triples:  The algorithm is as follows: `for i in V: for j in V: for k in V:  if every edge is incident to at least one of i,j,k, return True.`  That algorithm takes time $O(n^3 \cdot m)$.

Comment: So both problems are in P? m is count of edges?

Comment: For any _fixed_ $c \in \mathbb{N}$, the problem $c$-Vertex Cover, i.e., does a graph $G$ have a vertex cover of size at most $c$, is in $P$, yes.  In fact, it is solvable in time $n^c m$ for $m$ the number of edges.